# How to use CodeDom to create a designer of sorts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, codedom

EDIT : This is not winforms app, its a custom system that does not use visual studio at all. The winforms is just a sample of what I need, its not even remotely related to it at all.

I have a piece of software used to design some layouts, in a fashion similar to Visual Studio (alot simpler).
I have started looking into CodeDom, and I would like to know how VS handles the source generation for the designer.
Mostly what I am trying to accomplish is to generate a file similar to the designer file but for my OWN CUSTOM SYSTEM, thats UNRELATED to Winforms.

So lets say I have List, and I want to generate all the initialization code for each of those, which can be complex and have other Complex Objects inside.

One Requirement , and I am not even sure if its possible, I want to have types that define their own generated code, for instance :

```
//MyType A, when the code is generated it should be:
MyType name = SomethingElse.Load("somethingThatIGetFromtheOriginalControl");
```

Something like binary files are handled via the normal designer

I still very fresh, but all the tutorials and resources I have seen does not handle this, or I am not understanding it correctly, can anyone shed some light?

TLDR: I want to simulate what VS designer does in a smaller level.

Comment: 1) You can vote to reopen your question 2) Another possibility: delete it, think on the reasons, and come back in some days with a reformulated alternative.

Comment: Do you need to read the file afterwards? If you do, I would strongly advise you to avoid using C# files and instead use XAML, or something similar.

Comment: I am still unsure if I do need to read it, but I do have a option, of compiling the "form" and then loop through all the controls and recreate the designer, so this isnt a big deal =)